# Trying to derive an equation to express number of carps in play

Tags: linear-algebra

I play magic the gathering. This is the situation, without needing to know the rules:

You gain one total available "mana" per turn. So available mana = number of turns passed.

Your only creature, of which you have inexhaustible copies, costs 5 mana. You can play as many per turn as you have mana for.

So on turn five, you can play one. The same is true on turn 6, since 6 % 5 = 1.

So by the end of turn 6, you have two of these creatures in play: one from the previous turn, and one that you've just played. At the end of turn 7, there will be 3.

On turn ten, you can start playing two per turn, since 10 / 5 = 2.

How can I express the number of creatures played in this manner as a function of the number of turns that have passed for me?

Comment: Not at all sure if I tagged this  correctly.

Comment: For those who know the rules of magic, I'm trying to describe this joke deck mathematically http://tappedout.net/mtg-decks/ancient-carp/ , disregarding that you would soon empty your hand.

Comment: Mathematically, we can write $$n = \sum_{j = 1}^t \lfloor j/5 \rfloor$$ where $n$ is the number of carps on the field in a given turn, and $t$ is the number of the current turn, and $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ is the greatest integer function.

Comment: Wow that's really simple once you know the proper notation. Is there a way to represent that an as equation instead of a series?

Comment: Also: I guess you could say these are... magic-carps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way of writing it you might like: define $m =\lfloor t/5 \rfloor$, and we have
$$
n = 5\frac{m(m+1)}{2} + m(t \bmod 5)
$$
where $t \bmod 5$ is the remiander of the division $t \div 5$.